# How to generate citation call-outs to pieces with between 3 and 6 authors according to APA7 in LaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa7

My manuscript was accepted and the editors sent me the following recommendation:

> "Please make sure all the in-text references are in APA 7th edition
> style. In this style, references are set in parentheses, with & used
> before the last author's name and a comma and space before the date. **All authors (up to six) are given on the first reference, with et al. used on later references to the same work**. Please check that et al.
> always has a period".

I use the Overleaf platform to compile my LaTeX document. In the preamble, I load the `biblatex` package with the following options:

```
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,sorting=nyt,
    style=apa,uniquename=false,minnames=1, 
    maxnames=6, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
```

Options `minnames`, `maxnames` and `maxbibnames` don't work. I've ever tried with `minnames=6`, but all entries change to 6.

I thought of writing manually each entry with more than 6 authors, but I have some unique citations and they wouldn't be registered in the references section with this procedure.

How can I solve it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=apa,uniquename=false,minnames=1, maxnames=6, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{APA7 Example}
\author{filran}
\date{February 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\citet{GSwE2009} is the first citation and it should show up to 6 authors. Now, \citet{GSwE2009} should be show the first author and et al. after.

I'm following the recommendation according to an IEEE Journal: \textit{``Please make sure all the in-text references are in APA 7th edition style. In this style, references are set in parentheses, with & used before the last author's name and a comma and space before the date. All authors (up to six) are given on the first reference, with et al. used on later references to the same work. Please check that et al. always has a period".}

\printbibliography[notcategory={ps}]
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: `maxcitenames=6`? Try that in the `\usepackage[]{biblatex}` options. Could you please include  some code beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` as it is difficult if not impossible to help without seeing a minimized document, particularly the style issues.

Comment: show a small but complete example that demonstrates the problem and can be used for a test.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Doesn't setting `style=apa` suffice to implement the APA7 rules?

Comment: Where does "All authors (up to six) are given on the first reference, with et al. used on later references to the same work" come from? That was the rule for APA6, but it's no longer in force for APA7.

Comment: If you want real APA7 style, the only `biblatex` options you should be loading are `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, natbib=true,]{biblatex}` (the other options you had risk not being APA compliant). As Mico says, what the reviewers describe is APA6, APA7 only goes up to two names (usually), see https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/author-date for details.

Comment: Guys, I edited my question and I put the code and a print of the result.

Comment: Do feel free to take the code in the answer I posted and change `style=apa` to `style=apa6` to find out what citation call-outs and bibliographic entris formatted according to APA6 might look like.

Comment: Hi, all! I sent an email to the editor and he suggested following the apa-7 guidelines in https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/author-date. Apparently, there was confusing information in the editor's office. Thank you for all!

Comment: @filran - Thanks for letting us know about the happy ending to this saga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You urgently need to get in touch with the editorial team of your journal and inform them that their instructions for formatting citation call-outs are badly out of date.

- The citation call-out rules they quote -- for the most part, but see below for an exception -- applied under APA6. These rules are no longer correct for APA7. In particular, under APA7 the one and only relevant rule is that citation call-outs to *all pieces with 3 or more authors* get truncated immediately.
- Moreover, the rules they quote are not only out of date, in the sense that they don't conform to APA7 rules, they're not even fully correct for APA6! Under APA6, the rule for *all pieces with 6 or more authors* was to employ "et al." right away in citation call-outs. Only pieces with exactly 3, 4, or 5 authors would see all authors listed in the first citation call-out, with "et al." truncation applied to second and further citation call-outs.
- With a current version of `biblatex`, the only option you *must* set in order to get the citation call-outs conform to APA7 rules is `style=apa`. The option `natbib=true` is optional. The option `backend=biber` is fine, but this option has been the default for a number of years now. All other options you mention in your posting can only be counterproductive.

If nothing else, do get the journal's editorial team to state that they actually want APA6 rules, not APA7 rules, to apply. While you're at it, do get them to acknowledge that the APA6 rule they quote applies only to pieces with 3, 4, or 5 authors, and hence that it does not apply to pieces with exactly 6 authors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{b3,
  author = "A and B and C",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3003}
@misc{b4,
  author = "A and B and C and D",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3004}
@misc{b5,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3005}
@misc{b6,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3006}
@misc{b7,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3007}
@misc{b8,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3008}
@misc{b9,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3009}
@misc{b10,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3010}
@misc{b11,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3011}
@misc{b12,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K and L",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3012}
@misc{b13,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K and L and M",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3013}
@misc{b14,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K and L and M and N",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3014}
@misc{b15,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K and L and M and N and O",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3015}
@misc{b16,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K and L and M and N and O
        and P",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3016}
@misc{b17,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K and L and M and N and O
        and P and Q",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3017}
@misc{b18,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K and L and M and N and O
        and P and Q and R",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3018}
@misc{b19,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K and L and M and N and O
        and P and Q and R and S",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3019}
@misc{b20,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K and L and M and N and O
        and P and Q and R and S and T",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3020}
@misc{b21,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K and L and M and N and O
        and P and Q and R and S and T
        and U",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3021}
@misc{b22,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K and L and M and N and O
        and P and Q and R and S and T
        and U and V",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3022}
@misc{b23,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K and L and M and N and O
        and P and Q and R and S and T
        and U and V and W",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3023}
@misc{b24,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K and L and M and N and O
        and P and Q and R and S and T
        and U and V and W and X",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3024}
@misc{b25,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E 
        and F and G and H and I and J 
        and K and L and M and N and O
        and P and Q and R and S and T
        and U and V and W and X and Y",
  title  = "Thoughts", year = 3025}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

%% To generate APA6-conforming output, one could also 
%% execute the following two lines of code, using BibTeX:
%%\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
%%\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\cite{b3}; \cite{b4}; \cite{b5}. % first citation

\cite{b3}; \cite{b4}; \cite{b5}. % second (and further) citations

\medskip
\cite{b6},  \cite{b7},  \cite{b8},  \cite{b9},  

\cite{b10}, \cite{b11}, \cite{b12}, \cite{b13}, 

\cite{b14}, \cite{b15}, \cite{b16}, \cite{b17}, 

\cite{b18}, \cite{b19}, \cite{b20}, \cite{b21}, 

\cite{b22}, \cite{b23}, \cite{b24}, \cite{b25}.

\printbibliography
%%\bibliography{mybib} % for use with apacite package/bib style

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and suggestion. I sent right now an email about apa versions. However, I have only one week to do changes. While I won't have an answer, I'd like to get a "way" to deploy that requirement of up to 6 authors. I'll edit my question with code and link.

Comment: @filran - My honest recommendation to you would be to keep a very low profile, change the main `biblatex` option from `style=apa` to `style=apa6` (so as to switch to APA6 rules), and keep your fingers crossed that you don't have a lot of bibliographic entries with exactly six authors. That, or insist openly that you, not they, have the more accurate information as to what the APA6 rules actually say.